# Как обеспечить безопасность "Умного дома"?

Tags: безопасность, arduino

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, способы обеспечения информационной безопасности в системе "Умный дом", построенной на Arduino. Необходимо обеспечить безопасность каналов передачи данных.

Comment: Полной ИБ никак не обеспечить.